# What role was Irrfan Khan supposed to play?

Tags: character, casting, interstellar

I heard in lot of sources the information that Irrfan Khan was offered a role in *Interstellar* which he turned down due to the requirement of an extended stay in the US, when he couldn't have served that time.

But what was that role? While watching the movie I didn't notice any Indian ethnicity role there. What role was Irrfan supposed to play?

Comment: Pretty much all roles in that movie could be exchanged for any ethnicity. Of course characters that are related should look that way or there would have to be an excuse like adoption, also the professor had to be old, but other than that, no property of the characters really mattered for the plot.

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4667/49).

Answer (score 6):

As asked on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Was-Irrfan-Khan-offered-the-role-of-Dr-Cooper-in-the-movie-Interstellar-before-Matthew-McConaughey-If-so-then-why-did-he-reject-such-a-career-changing-role), they all made some pretty good points there, and ever since then there wasn't any new information that came to light.

> But what was that role? While watching the movie I didn't notice any Indian ethnicity role there. What role was Irrfan supposed to play?

One of the posters in Quora even mentioned about the possibility of the role being [Doyle's, played by Wes Bentley](https://interstellarfilm.fandom.com/wiki/Doyle)

In another [article](https://www.scoopwhoop.com/entertainment/irrfan-khan-turned-down-roles-alongside-leonardo-di-caprio-scarlett-johanson-to-work-in-bollywood/),

> He was also asked to be a part of Christopher Nolan’s Interstellar which he turned down because he didn't want to let go of The Lunchbox and D-Day, two Hindi films he had already made a commitment to. **Rumours suggest he was offered the role of Matt Damon or David Gyasi in the film.**